# Integral problem: what is answer of this integral?

Tags: integration

what is answer of this integral:
$\int_o^{\infty}\sqrt x \sinh x dx$

(it is not in my math book)
point:
$\int_o^{\infty}\sqrt x \cosh x dx- \int_o^{\infty}\sqrt x \sinh x dx=\sqrt \pi$

Comment: No wonder! It blows up.

Comment: @André Nicolas so why it gives result, take a look to the point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral does not converge. Express $\sinh x$ in terms of exponentials. The integral $\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}e^x\,dx$ blows up, while $\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}e^{-x}\,dx$ is well-behaved.

**Remark:** An edit to the problem seems to indicate you are interested in $\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}(\cosh x-\sinh x)\,dx$. Expressing the hyperbolic functions in terms of exponentials, we arrive at $\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}e^{-x}\,dx$. If you make the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$, you will arrive at what is probably a familiar integral.

Comment: it seems gamma function!